# What's The Best Way To Collect A Lot Of Information From User?

Tags: iphone, xcode10, swift4.1

I'm just learning Swift and IOS development. I have an issue, I'm creating an app that need's to get a lot of information about a product, from the user. There will be many fields the user needs to fill out about this product.

At first, I just added some labels and below each label a text field for the user to fill in information for each label. However, I found out that I quickly ran out of room for my labels and text fields.

So my question is What would be the best Object to use to collect all this information. Also, this information will be saved to Realm database, and each product will then be displayed on a table view when the app opens. Then when the user clicks the product it will show them all the stored information about that product. Also when they click the + in the navigation bar it will let them add a new product and all the information for it.

So that is how my app will function. Any help on the best way to collect and display this vast amount of information would be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wanting to learn how to do this in this video. How or where can I learn how to display edit and save tableview information like this https://www.elitexcoders.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/TBExample.mp4

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to categorize the information and show the input fields of each category in a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of which information you want. IOS development is not like Android, that you can call an Intent to access almost everything in device. but, with Custom URL, you can access address contacts, calls, messages. You can access the photo library, capture geolocation. Apple is much more restrictive then Google.

Comment: I want to use a table view to display all product names, then when user clicks on one product, it loads the products information into another tableview in sections, like a section for Name, Size, Color, Date Purchashed etc, then let the user beable to edit that data in the tableview and it saves to database or updates. However I can't find a tutorial on how to do this, I've tried searching tableviews edit, custom cells, i get back a bunch of things that don't help me. like how to edit/ delete tableview by swiping. But if someone can point me to a place where I can learn that that would be cool